# How do I get org-mode to treat the output of a non-latex code block as latex?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, python

(Emacs: v27.1, Org: v9.5, pdfTeX: v3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21)

I am using the following Python code block to print LaTeX code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :exports both :results output :wrap math
...
#+END_SRC
```

That prints:

```
M^{1} = \left[\begin{matrix}15000.0 \\ 15000.0\end{matrix}\right] \\
...
```

However, when I export to a LaTeX document, it is interpreted as:

```
M\textsuperscript{1} = [15000.0 $\backslash$\ 15000.0] \\
...
```

And that causes the LaTeX compilation to fail. How can I prevent Emacs from reinterpreting the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change `:wrap math` to `:wrap export latex`.

That should wrap the output in a `#+begin_latex:` block, which should in turn export the way you want.

Comment: Wrap just sets the value inside of the `\begin{}` and `\end{}` blocks surrounding the output. So `:wrap latex` does `\begin{latex} ... \end{latex}`

Comment: yes, I edited the answer, it should be :wrap export latex. Then it exports the correct way for me.